# Cannot find module "." issue with TypedJSON library and Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, webpack, ionic2

I have the following issue while doing an ionic 2 serve command using TypedJSON library :

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:82208:69)
    at METADATA_FIELD_KEY (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:82208:147)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:82213:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:94414:86)

[...]
```

I can reproduce it with a simple app. 
Here are my step :

//Installing last ionic version

```
npm install -g ionic@latest cordova typescript
```

//Creating a new app

```
ionic start test blank --v2
```

//Installing webpack support

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

//Installing TypedJSON

```
npm install typedjson-npm
```

//Installing typings

```
typings install npm:typedjson-npm
```

I created a simple model :

```
import { JsonMember, JsonObject } from 'typedjson-npm';

@JsonObject
export class GeoJsonModel {

  @JsonMember
  type: string;

  public getType() {
    return this.type;
  }

}
```

And here is my home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GeoJsonModel } from '../../models/geojson-model';
import { TypedJSON } from 'typedjson-npm';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    var geo= TypedJSON.parse('{ "type": "geojson"}', GeoJsonModel);

    console.log("hello world");
    console.log(geo instanceof GeoJsonModel);
    console.log(geo.getType());


  }

}
```

I also tried to import Typed JSON with typedjson-npm/js/typed-json without any success.

Thank you for your help

Comment: A workaround has been proposed in https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON/issues/73